# How do I know if the current request is using ssl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I tell if the current request is using ssl or not?

What about if the port is other than port 80?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

request.ssl? will be true and request.port will give you the port the quest was on.

Answer (score 1):

```
request.ssl
```

Should tell you

Source: http://www.rubyinside.com/19-rails-tricks-most-rails-coders-dont-know-131.html